# How to draw lines between records for plain text output format (.txt)?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, plaintext

My problem is that when i try to export the jasperprint to text, the lines/rectangles doesn't appear in the .txt files though it works with pdf files.

I tried to modify the pen width but nothing appear .

My code is:

```
JRDesignLine ltest = new JRDesignLine();
ltest.setBackcolor(Color.black);
ltest.setForecolor(Color.black);
ltest.setX(10);
ltest.setY(200);
ltest.setMode(JRDesignStaticText.MODE_OPAQUE);
ltest.setWidth(500);
ltest.setHeight(10);
ltest.setPen(JRDesignLine.FILL_SOLID);
bandHeader.addElement(ltest);
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Do you mean the plain text format?

Comment: What exporter did you use?

Comment: JRDesignLine ltest = new JRDesignLine();
                        ltest.setBackcolor(Color.black);
                        ltest.setForecolor(Color.black);
                        ltest.setX(10);
                        ltest.setY(200);
                        ltest.setMode(JRDesignStaticText.MODE_OPAQUE);
                        ltest.setWidth(500);
                         ltest.setHeight(10);
                        ltest.setPen(JRDesignLine.FILL_SOLID); 
                        bandHeader.addElement(ltest);

Comment: yes alex k , i mean the plain text format and i used the JRTextExporter

Comment: I've added another 2 solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about the [plain text format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text) and it is very simple.

#### The problem

The [*JRTextExporter*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRTextExporter.html) is skipping *JRLine* elements and does not draw the borders (*JRLineBox*).

The snippet of *JRTextExporter*:

```
protected void exportElements(List<JRPrintElement> elements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        Object element = elements.get(i);
        if (element instanceof JRPrintText) {
            exportText((JRPrintText) element);
        } else if (element instanceof JRPrintFrame) {
            JRPrintFrame frame = (JRPrintFrame) element;
            setFrameElementsOffset(frame, false);
            try {
                exportElements(frame.getElements());
            } finally {
                restoreElementOffsets();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see only the *JRPrintText* will be prinited. And the *protected void exportText(JRPrintText)* method does not know anything about Boxes. You can compare it whith the source of *JRRtfExporter.exportText(JRPrintText)* method.

#### Solutions

- You can try to use *rtf* output format (*JRRtfExporter*)
- Another idea (not elegant and a little bit ugly) is to use *staticText* or *textField* (with or without condition) to simulate borders.
- You can try to set [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.line.separator*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.line.separator) property. For example you can set value: `&#xD;&#xA;_________________________________________________________&#xD;&#xA;`. It is \r\n at the start, the some numbers of underscore and \r\n at the end of line. The reports properties can be something like this:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.page.height" value="66"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.page.width" value="94"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.line.separator" value="&#xD;&#xA;_________________________________________________________&#xD;&#xA;"/>
```

- The output can be look better with *JRCsvExporter* and [*net.sf.jasperreports.csv.field.delimiter*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.csv.field.delimiter), [*net.sf.jasperreports.csv.record.delimiter*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.csv.record.delimiter) properties

Comment: thank you alex, i use the JRRtfExporter and it solve the problem of lines. the problem is when i want to change the  font map to time new roman nothing change :

Comment: here is the source code ; 
    JRRtfExporter exporter = new JRRtfExporter();  
     HashMap fontMap = new HashMap();
     FontKey key = new FontKey("Times New Roman", true, false);
     RtfFont font = new RtfFont("Arial", 9, RtfFont.NORMAL);
     fontMap.put(key, font);
     exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.FONT_MAP,fontMap);            
     exporter.exportReport();

Comment: It is better to ask a new question